# Не выбирает нужную таблицу в БД для сохранения, что делать? python 3.8

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite3

найдите ошибку в этой части кода!
Не могу понять, почему, когда юзер вводит значение для **s_input**, оно(значение) не сравнивается с v, v1, v2 и тд. а выбирается первый **if**?
Как сделать так, чтобы выбиралась нужная таблица в БД?
Все **import** соблюдены, база данных существует и находится в папке с проектом, и консоль не выводит **Traceback**!

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('logbd.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

s_input = str(input('Введите имя сервиса(Например, Vk.com или Vkontakte):\n '))
login_input = input('Login(Иногда это почта):\n ')
password_input = input('Password:\n ')
s = 'Steam'
s1 = 'steam'
s2 = 'стим'
v = 'Vk'
v1 = 'Vkontakte'
v2 = 'vkontakte'
albums = [(s_input, login_input, password_input)]
if s_input == v or v1 or v2:
    name = input('Введите имя аккаунта:\n')
    albums = [(name, login_input, password_input)]
    albums_print = (name, login_input, password_input)
    cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO vk VALUES (?,?,?)", albums)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    print('Успешно!')   
elif s_input == s or s1 or s2:
    name = input('Введите имя аккаунта:\n')
    albums = [(name, login_input, password_input)]
    albums_print = (name, login_input, password_input)
    cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO steam VALUES (?,?,?)", albums)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    print('Успешно!')
else:
    cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO logpass VALUES (?,?,?)", albums)
    conn.commit()#Сохраняем
    conn.close()
```

Comment: `if s_input == v or v1 or v2` у тебя всегда будет истинным, так как для строк это эквивалентно следующему условию:  `if s_input == v or v1!="" or v2!=""`, а v1 и в v2  у тебя не пустые строки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если ты хотел, что бы в первый `if` входило, только если пользователь введет `Vk`, `Vkontakte` или `vkontakte`, тогда должно быть так:
`if s_input in [v, v1, v2]:`
или
`if s_input == v or s_input == v1 or s_input == v2:`